# The multi-part identifier "System.Data.DataRowView" could not be bound

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have a table that populate Combobox1 and Combobox1 should populate Combobox2 and this is where the problem is.
That's the exception i'm getting

> The multi-part identifier "System.Data.DataRowView" could not be bound.

Code :

```
    private void frm2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Populate Combobox1
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT CategoryID, Name FROM Categories", clsMain.con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "CategoryID";
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //populate Combobox2
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT SubCategoryID, Name FROM SubCategories WHERE CategoryID=" + comboBox1.SelectedValue, clsMain.con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        comboBox2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox2.ValueMember = "SubCategoryID";
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to loading second combobox while filling data in first combo. 
You can avoid this error by: 
1. Use *SelectionChangeCommitted* event instead of *SelectedIndexChanged* event. 
Or 
2. Detach selected index change event, populate combobox, attach event again as:

```
private void frm2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Detach event
   comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged -= comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;

    //Populate Combobox1
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT CategoryID, Name FROM Categories", clsMain.con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "CategoryID";

   //Attach event again
    comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
}
```

Hopes this will help you.

Comment: I didn't think it would be that easy.
Both ways worked just fine, I can't thank you enough for your help, That was very helpful..Thanks :)