# Unhandled Exception when Filling a datagrid View

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm working on a C# winform application. My goal is after the user picked a date from the datetimePicker, a query is performed and returns results with only identical records. Next, the user will select one of these records which should fill the grid with all items ordered associated with that customer from a combobox (custlocation)  This part is working. Problem is, now I've been stuck trying to get my dataGridView1 to populate. I keep getting:

> an unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

I've checked my query and it returns the correct results.

```
private void custlocation_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(
        "Select [orderitem].*, [orderitem].qty, [orderitem].descrip, [orderitem].tally "+
        "from [orderitem] inner join [Order] on [orderitem].orderId = [order].ct "+
        "where [order].loadDate='" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Date + "' "+
        "and [order].addr1=" + custlocation.Text, conn);

    DataTable lt = new DataTable();
    //da.Fill(lt);

    //dataGridView1.DataSource = lt;
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = lt;
    dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "loadtickets";
    dataGridView1.Rows[a].Cells[0].Value = rdr["orderID"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[a].Cells[1].Value = rdr["qty"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[a].Cells[2].Value = rdr["descrip"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[a].Cells[3].Value = rdr["tally"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception?  You're using a lot of array indexers there, it would appear that one of them is incorrect (or assuming an incorrect state).  When you debug this, when the exception is thrown, what index are you trying to access and why do you think it should exist?

Comment: I get the exemption on line 5.  This should pull multiple line items to fill the grid.

Comment: And which line is "line 5"?  (Hint: In the code sample posted, the 5th line is commented out.)  Additionally, when you debug it, examine the actual runtime values of the objects you're using.  You are trying to access a value which isn't there.

Comment: Try stepping through in debug mode, though I note that it appears you're using code from a datareader insert loop (rdr) that isn't defined anywhere in the posted code block.

Comment: It's most likely that either `a` is out of range for the rows or there aren't 4 cells in a row.

Comment: If I see well, You took 4 columns from database, and fill `dataGridView`, but You try to set name for non existing column (0..3 = 4 columns, `.Column[4].Name...` is 5th column which doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are zero-based, like you used on the `Cells` property. Seems you are trying to change the name of the 5th column, but you only have 4.

Change

```
dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "loadtickets";
```

To

```
dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "loadtickets";
```

Comment: I'm now having The multi-part identifier "System.Data.DataRowView" could not be bound.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075640/the-multi-part-identifier-system-data-datarowview-could-not-be-bound)

Answer (score 0):

> an unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

This error is because you have to use `dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "loadtickets";` like [@Anderson Pimentel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1084168/anderson-pimentel) said.

> The multi-part identifier "System.Data.DataRowView" could not be bound

This error is because of the query.

```
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(
    "Select [orderitem].*, [orderitem].qty, [orderitem].descrip, [orderitem].tally "+
    "from [orderitem]  inner join [Order] on [orderitem].orderId = [order].ct "+
    "where [order].loadDate='" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Date + "' "+
    "and [order].addr1=" + custlocation.Text, conn);
```

you have selected `orderitm.*` (all columns from `orderitem`) and 3 columns from the same table (`[orderitem].qty, [orderitem].descrip, [orderitem].tally`). so these columns are duplicated

You have to remove these duplicates or give them aliases like the `[orderitem].qty AS Quantity`