# C# database selection

Tags: c#, database, listview, listbox

I have two databases. The first one is shown via a `ListBox`, and the second one via a `ListView`. I want to be able to show some information in the `ListView` based on the chosen `ListBox` element, but my code doesn't work.

```
private void DpListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    L.InitReadOnly(false, NameF, LastNameF, AgeF, DepartmentF, ProfessionF, SalaryF);
    L.InitReadOnly(false, Name4, LastName4, Age4, Department4, Profession4, Salary4);
    int counter = 0;
    IEnumerable<Employee> critCareEmp;
    critCareEmp = L.EmpUpdate(counter, Emp, DpListBox, Ep);

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    Console.WriteLine(DpListBox.SelectedValue.ToString());
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand($@"SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE Dep_nt={DpListBox.SelectedValue}", connection);
    adapter.SelectCommand = command;
    DataTable dataTable1 = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(dataTable1);
    Ep.ItemsSource = dataTable1.DefaultView;
}
```

It seems that I need `DpListBox.SelectedValue` to be some kind of string, but it's not.

Comment: Which error exactly you are getting?

Comment: How are you loading data in `DpListBox`? What data you are loading in `DpListBox`? If datatype of `Dep_nt` column in database is string then you should have `Dep_nt='{DpListBox.SelectedValue}'` in the sql query.

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "The multi-part identifier "System.Data.DataRowView" could not be bound."

Comment: Which line of code gives the error?

Comment: DpListBox loaded with database the data in it just strings

Comment: SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT DepartmentName FROM Department ", connection);
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dataTable);
            DpListBox.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;

Comment: adapter.Fill(dataTable1); gives error

Comment: You should mention the error in the question. And also try to search around that error. You need to update the question and share the code there itself. Looks like you have `SelectedIndexChanged` or some other event associated with the `Ep` ListView. if you have search in google for the error you are getting you would have got the [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075640/the-multi-part-identifier-system-data-datarowview-could-not-be-bound) as first result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand
        ($@"SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE Dep_nt="+ 
           DpListBox.SelectedValue.ToString(), 
           connection);
```

please use  parameterized stored procedure 
inline query is such a bad practice

Comment: i still get the same error as before, i think it is because DpListBox.SelectedValue.ToString() = System.Data.DataRowView and it contains two fields id and DepartmentName, i need to somehow choose one of them (DepartmentName) but i don't know how

Comment: how you will bind data in dropdown the problem should occur there